# 3D Secure songbird js CSP requirements

Tags: braintree, 3d-secure

Our site uses a content security policy with Braintree's implementation of 3D Secure.

There are multiple calls made by songbird.js ([CardinalCommerce](https://cardinaldocs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CC/pages/131806/Getting+Started) implementation of 3D Secure used by Braintree) to third party sites (such as kg668dbov0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, touchtechpayments.com, or arcot.com) which are not documented in the CSP requirements outlined by Braintree here https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/.

These calls to third party sites don't seem to be documented anywhere on the web either, and seem to change at random. Every time there is an undocumented change it breaks our 3DS integration (iFrame doesn't load as the undocumented url is blocked by the CSP).

The urls seem to vary based on the card used (touchtechpayments.com seems to be the Revolut one, arcot.com seems to be HSBC), and I can see a couple others for French banks in our CSP violation report: https://bred.wlp-acs.com for Bred, https://bnpp-3ds.wlp-acs.com for BNP Paribas).

Does anyone know where I can find an up to date list of the content security policy requirements for songbird.js ?

Answer (score 1):

I've created an issue on the braintree github page:
https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/497

My list so far:

- 3ds-secure.cardcomplete.com
- ecclients.btrl.ro
- bofp.erstebank.hu
- www.clicksafe.lloydstsb.com
- pay.activa-card.com
- 3dsecure-1.wirecard.com
- 3dsecure-2.wirecard.com
- acssv.otpbank.hu
- acs.sia.eu
- idcheck.acs.touchtechpayments.com
- sicher-bezahlen.sparkasse.at
- secure5.arcot.com

Comment: Also facing similar issue with Cardinal.
Any workaround yet?

We are thinking of dynamic whitelisting, save it in DB and keep updating them whenever new url comes.